# Logout not working Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm building a Django website, but my logout is not working. The site consists in two apps, the *main* app that is public and the *student* app that is private. In my *student* app i've put the **@login_required** decorator in every method, except the logout method. But when i click the *logout* link in the *student* app, my page is not redirected to the *main* app, it goes to another view inside the *student* app, and when i reload the page, the content is still available although i've put the **@login_required** decorator. Here is my code:

**website/urls.py**

```
from main_app import urls as main_urls
from student_app import urls as std_urls

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^index/', include(main_urls)),
url(r'^student-area/', include(std_urls))]
```

**website/settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/index/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/student-area/'
```

**main_app/urls.py**

```
...
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
...]
```

**student_app/urls.py**

```
...
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.std_videos_view, name='student_area'),
url(r'^(?P<video_key>[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)/$', views.std_video_detail_view, name='video_detail'),
url(r'^materials-std/$', views.std_material_view, name='materials_std_view'),
url(r'^download-material/(?P<material_key>[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)/$', views.std_material_download, name='download_material'),
url(r'^sims/$', views.std_sim_view, name='sims_view'),
url(r'^download-sim/(?P<sim_key>[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)/$', views.std_sim_download, name='download_sim'),
url(r'^contact/$', views.std_contact_view, name='std_contact'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout')
]
```

**student_app/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('index')
```

**student_app/templates/student_area.html**

```
...
<a href={% url 'user_logout' %} class="btn btn-default">Logout</a>
...
```

I am lost in this problem, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `video_detail` URL pattern matches `/logout/`. Django stops as soon as it finds a match, so requests for `/logout/` will be handled by the `std_video_detail_view` view instead of the `user_logout` view.

You can fix this by either changing the regex for the `video_detail` URL so that it doesn't clash (for example you could use `^videos/(?P<video_key>[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)/$`), or by moving the logout URL pattern above the video detail pattern.

Comment: sorry, i forgot the *return* only in the question. But i've put the $ in the logout url and did not work.

Comment: If the problem is caused by a missing `$` then it will be one of the URL patterns above the logout URL pattern. I used `user_logout` as an example because you haven't shown the rest of your urls.

Comment: i edited the question with the other urls, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: OK, I can see the problem now that you've added your URL patterns - see the updated answer.